# How to merge Windows recovery disk images?

Tags: windows, disk-image, recovery-disk

I have 3 Windows 7 recovery disk images (.iso files). How do I marge them into 1 disk image so I can put it into my pen drive?

I don't have any disks and don't want to buy anything. I try partitioning off 3 parts of my flash drive and putting disk 1 with the boot loader on the first etc., but it didn't recognize the other partitions.

I prefer methods that work in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.easy2boot.com/make-an-easy2boot-usb-drive/make-using-linux/

You can use linux to make an easy2boot USB drive

Answer (score 0):

Check my answer here:

[How to create bootable USB stick with GRUB with data partition, Win rescue disk and System Rescue CD](https://superuser.com/questions/756193/how-to-create-bootable-usb-stick-with-grub-with-data-partition-win-rescue-disk/756277#756277)

I personally use Easy2Boot, no need to manually make multiple partitions,
after you prepare the drive with Easy2Boot program, you can simply
copy the 3 .ISO files to the designated folder on the usb drive,
and choose which one to start when booting from usb drive.

You will not have to buy or burn anything.

This is windows software, at the end of your post you posted `Instictions:Ubuntu`
I'm not sure what you wanted to say, do you need instructions to do the same from Ubuntu Linux?

Comment: Yea I use Ubuntu

Comment: Right now I have no access to winodow tools since now I don't have windows on any of my computers

Comment: @MathCubes - Maybe you can run Windows in a VM to play / work with Easy2Boot.

Comment: @MathCubes - SteveSi - Maker of Easy2Boot has posted an easier better answer - Do select it.